# Recording and Uploading Audio with Silverlight 4

Tags: upload, silverlight-4.0, audio-recording

I've been reading about Silverlight 4's support for web cam and microphone.  I'd like to be able to record audio from the browser and upload it to an ASP.NET MVC site.  I've seen some mixed information about whether uploads are supported in Silverlight 4.  I'm also looking to encode the audio to MP3 before upload and have seen some references to Speex.

Does anyone have any experience with this scenario that they can share as to whether this will be possible with Silverlight 4?

Your expertise is greatly appreciated!

Comment: +1. This is a great question, I can see a lot of application for this kind of scenario (language training, voice prompts, telecom, etc.). Would love to see great answers on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that you can record the audio and upload it to the website. but I don't think there is any Silverlight library that you can use to convert your audio file to mp3. You can always convert it at server-side after uploading as well..

If your SL is trusted OOB application then you can try this http://alvasnet.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-save-audio-to-mp3-on-silverlight.html

Comment: Unfortunally this solution based on registration of the .net dll wrapped in com on the user's computer in GAC.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly upload any SL4 microphone output to an ASP.NET MVC (or WCF WebAPI) service.  I do this in my WP7 project.

As far as encoding, the raw PCM that comes out of the mic is typically huge (for a 16khz sample rate, 16bits/sample, mono channel audio stream, that would net out to 32000 bytes per second of audio).

I have not found an easy (or free) way to encode in MP3 on the SL platform, but fortunately, speech (as opposed to music) is better encoded using the Speex codec.  The implementation I use is at [nspeex.codeplex.com](http://nspeex.codeplex.com/) and has given me excellent compression ratios - e.g. at Quality level 1 (lowest out of 10, which is adequate for my purposes), 64k of audio (the equivalent of 2sec) will encode down to about 1500 bytes.